# trying to add a reassignment to append the special newline character to a string in Obj C

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to C and need to solve what I'm sure is a very simple problem.  How do I add a reassignment to append for a newline in Objective C.  The hint given was append @"\n".  I want my output to appear on a new line.  My code is below:

```
- (IBAction)displaySomeText: (id)sender

{

    WonderfulNumber *myWonderfulNumber = [WonderfulNumber wonderfulNumberWithFloat:pi];

    NSString *stringToOutput = @"The value is: ";

    stringToOutput = [stringToOutput stringByAppendingString:[myWonderfulNumber storedNumberAsString]];

    [textView insertText:stringToOutput];

}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
stringToOutput = [stringToOutput stringByAppendingFormat: @"\n%@",[myWonderfulNumber storedNumberAsString]];
```

Comment: It is unclear exactly where you want the newline. Max has put it before your number (interpreting "my output to appear on a new line"), but maybe you want it at the start?

Try replacing your two lines with `NSString *stringToOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\nThe value is: %@", [myWonderfulNumber storedNumberAsString]];` - and you can place the `\n` wherever you wish in the string.

Comment: After the the string prints, would like new text to display on new line when the button is pressed.  Desired result looks like this:                            The value is: 3.14 \n                                                   The value is: 3.14                                                     When I input recommended code, output displayed like:                    The value is: 3.14 \n                                                  3.14

Comment: Disregard previous reply - completed as you suggested and it worked!!  Thanks!

Comment: found another solution: `code` - (IBAction)displaySomeText:(id)sender
{
 WonderfulNumber *myWonderfulNumber = [WonderfulNumber wonderfulNumberWithFloat:pi];
 
 NSString *stringToOutput = @"The value is: ";
 
 stringToOutput = [stringToOutput stringByAppendingString:[myWonderfulNumber storedNumberAsString]];
 
 stringToOutput = [stringToOutput stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
 
 [textView insertText:stringToOutput];
} `code`

Comment: sorry - (IBAction)displaySomeText:(id)sender
{
 WonderfulNumber *myWonderfulNumber = [WonderfulNumber wonderfulNumberWithFloat:pi];
 
 NSString *stringToOutput = @"The value is: ";
 
 ***stringToOutput = [stringToOutput stringByAppendingString:[myWonderfulNumber storedNumberAsString]];***
 
 ***stringToOutput = [stringToOutput stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];***
 
 [textView insertText:stringToOutput];
}

Comment: yes, there are lots of different ways. but i suggest to use the shortest one